# How to get html information by Python3

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, tabs

I am trying to get the data from url. The partial html tab is shown below and I would like to get the number "397" which will be changed all the time just like stock index. My code is shown below, and when I compile the .py file, the result is `<a class="p_total" name="p_bar_total"></a>` without the number.

Html:

```
<div id="p_bar_bottom" class="p_bar" style="display: inline;">
            <a name="p_bar_total" class="p_total">&nbsp;397&nbsp;</a>
            <a name="p_bar_min" class="p_redirect" style="display: none;">|‹ 1</a>
```

Code:

```
with requests.session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.sth.com'
    page = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    total_list = soup.find(class_ = 'p_bar')
    total_no_list = total_list.find(class_ = 'p_total')
    print(total_no_list)
```

Are there something wrong about my code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not need to find two tags to get the text you can directly get the text!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
html = '''<div id="p_bar_bottom" class="p_bar" style="display: inline;">
            <a name="p_bar_total" class="p_total">&nbsp;397&nbsp;</a>
            <a name="p_bar_min" class="p_redirect" style="display: none;">|‹ 1</a>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

total = soup.select('.p_total')[0].text
print(total)
```

Output:

```
397
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think your method is work but I just realized that the problem is not how to showing the number. When I print out the "soup", the "number" is missing already like that <a name="p_bar_total" class="p_total"></a>. But other tabs work fine.  What's problem causing this? Thanks again!!

Comment: can you share the url please

Comment: Sorry, it requires login, but I can share the related html with you. When I review the html again, I find that the "number" is actually a variable but I have not idea about how to get the variable from html:

Comment: `var vmdata = { vmcount : 548}

                                      function refreshBar(objid){
   var barsize = divchildren["p_bar_num"].length;
   divchildren["p_bar_total"][0].innerHTML = '&nbsp;' + vmdata.vmcount + '&nbsp;';
   obj = divchildren["p_bar_min"][0];}
                                 </form>
     <tr>
      <td valign="top">
       <div class="p_bar" id="p_bar_top">
        <a class="p_total" name="p_bar_total">
        </a>`
Sorry about the format. It has characters limit and can't start a newline. The above code has 3 part: var, function and html form.

Comment: This is javascript, not html. `BeautifulSoup` doesn't execute javascript, so you either have to use a headless browser or manually parse the javascript to get the 'vmcount' value.